# Expo react-native Error: URL.search is not implemented when working with openai.createImage General API discussion

Tags: react-native, openai-api

this is my function

```
async function generateImage() {
    try {
      const response = await openai.createImage({
        prompt: 'a white siamese cat',
        n: 1,
        size: '1024x1024',
      });
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

i am getting this error when using on mobile :
Error: URL.search is not implemented

i am really stuck in this one so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7):

i found the solution you have to install npm install react-native-url-polyfill
and import "react-native-url-polyfill/auto" in your App.js

Comment: Marking commands and small snippets as "Code Sample"  would make the answer easier to visually parse. Ex: Use command `cd /home/user`.

Comment: Thanks, mate, this resolved my issue with the "Error: URL.search is not implemented" error msg.

Answer (score 7):

You should use [react-native-url-polyfill](https://github.com/charpeni/react-native-url-polyfill). It's a homemade `polyfill` to implement the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).

```bash
$ yarn add react-native-url-polyfill
```

or

```bash
$ npm install react-native-url-polyfill --save
```

At the top of your entry-point file `(index.js)`, the polyfill will be automatically applied.

```js
/**
 * @format
 */

import "react-native-url-polyfill/auto"
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Then just use the url api in any files without any `import`

```js
    const _url = new URL(url)
    const params = _url.searchParams
    const routeName = _url.hostname
    ...
```

I hope it will help :)

Comment: I had to manually add `import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';` at the top of `index.js`; and then it worked!